# Broadcasting in Aloha omnet example

Tags: omnet++

I have to do broadcasting in the aloha project in order to find the neighbor of nodes.

please tell me how to do broadcasting in it by writing my own code.
I have tried this for loop but it is not working there.

```
for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
{
    send(msgB->dup(),"gate$o",k);
}
delete msgB;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aloha is a wireless network (i.e. no connections between hosts) so you should use `sendDirect()` calls to send messages to other hosts. Having a for loop is fine, but the `send()` call assumes that the gate used for sending is connected to the destination (which is not).

Comment: I changed the sendDirect() function to the following loop but I'm getting error that
 Assert condition msg==endTxEvent false in function handle message Host.cc line 62     
 for(int i=0; i<5 ;i++)
                {
                sendDirect(pk->dup(), radioDelay, duration, gate("checknode"));
                }
             delete pk;
Do i need to write something in the handle message function?

Comment: Yes. The code that handles the received message. On the other hand Aloha is a client-server example not an ad-hoc network so your requirement (i.e. to find the neighbor nodes) does not make sense in this context. There is no neighbors because hosts never communicate directly with each other. (and that's why the simulation fails. Hosts does not expect to receive anything from the outside world). You have probably chosen a wrong starting point (aloha) for your simulation project.

Comment: Thank you Rudi.
will you please suggest me a good simple example which help me in understanding the channel access mechanism and find the neighbors. I Have to work on ad-hoc nodes time synchronization specifically on MAC layer.

Comment: I am new to computer networks algorithms as well. I have to work a lot in order to understand them.

Comment: If you want to work with wireless networks the INET Wireless Tutorial is a MUST read: https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless After that you should take a look at ad-hoc networks, probably on routing. But it really depends on your exact project goal (i.e how detailed your simulation should be and what you want to achieve).  As you are speaking about "neighbours" I assume that at least the radios in your project should have a limited transmission range so the simple wireless example from OMNeT++ samples (aloha) will not do. You need to take a look at INET.

Comment: Thank you so much Rudi. I started watching the tutorials. But there is a problem. My supervisor is insisting me to try Aloha protocol. Is there any way to use it in all nodes case? I tried it but it got so complicated! will you please look into the project?

Comment: I spent a lot of time in understanding aloha example and to use it in my project. All in vain.

Comment: From wikipedia: Two fundamental choices which dictated much of the ALOHAnet design were the two-channel star configuration of the network and the use of random accessing for user transmissions. In a star topology, speaking about broadcast is meaningless. Anything that is transmitted by a client can be received ONLY by the central server. The server may later decide to broadcast that information to ALL clients (on a different radio channel which is owned exclusively by the server). In short, as I suggested earlier your original goal does not make sense (if you insist using ALOHA)

Comment: It makes sense. My goal is to do time synchronization of nodes, frame length selection and slot assignment in adhoc networks. Will the inet wireless tutorials are enough for me to begin working on these goals?

Comment: Yes, if you are working on adhoc network, INET is the way to go. The aloha example would not lead you anywhere.